Circular Dendrogram Difficulty
I'm looking to create a circular diagram that resembles the attached photo. I like that there are symptom clusters as an inner circle and then connectors from the clusters to each individual symptom in an outer circle. However, I'm having trouble replicating it.

My code is below, as well as the dataset:
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

# Load the data
data <- read_excel("Final.xlsx")

# Create a unique list of symptoms and clusters for vertices
vertices <- data.frame(name = unique(c(data$Symptom, data$Cluster)))

# Create edges for the graph
edges <- data.frame(from = data$Cluster, to = data$Symptom)

# Create a graph object
graph <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = vertices, directed = FALSE)

# Add a cluster column to vertices
vertices <- vertices %>%
  mutate(cluster = ifelse(name %in% data$Cluster, name, "Symptom"))

# Ensure the graph object has the updated vertices data
V(graph)$cluster <- vertices$cluster[match(V(graph)$name, vertices$name)]

# Plot the network graph
ggraph(graph, layout = 'circle') + 
  geom_edge_link(aes(color = from), alpha = 0.8) +
  geom_node_point(aes(color = cluster), alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 3) +
  scale_color_manual(values = rainbow(length(unique(vertices$cluster)))) +
  theme_void() +
  labs(title = "Network Graph of Symptoms by Symptom Cluster")




Cluster
Symptom




Arthritis/Myalgias
New Muscle Aches (myalgia), Joint Aches, Body Aches, or Pain


Autonomic
Fast-beating or Pounding Heart (heart palpitations)


Autonomic
Dizziness


Cardiac
Fast-beating or Pounding Heart (heart palpitations)


Cardiac
Chest Pain


Cognitive
Brain Fog (worsened memory or concentration)


Cognitive
Confusion


Dermatologic
Hair Loss


Dermatologic
Rash


Fatigue
Fatigue or Tiredness


Fever/Chills
Fever or Feeling Feverish


Fever/Chills
Chills


Gastrointestinal
Diarrhea


Gastrointestinal
Nausea


Mood
Feeling Anxious or Worried


Mood
Feeling Depressed


Mood
Other Mood Changes


Multisystem Inflammatory Syndrome
Multisystem Inflammatory Syndrome, MIS


Neurologic
Headache


Neurologic
Change in Smell


Neurologic
Change in Taste


Neurologic
Loss or Change in Vision


Neurologic
Tinnitus (ringing in ears)


Respiratory
Cough


Respiratory
Sore Throat


Respiratory
Runny Nose and/or Nasal Congestion


Respiratory
Shortness of Breath (Dyspnea) or Difficulty Breathing


Sleep
Sleep Problems



This code resulted in the following image:

As you can see, there are not two distinct circles and I am having trouble getting that to work. Any help is appreciated!

Instead of using ggraph here is an approach which comes close to your desired result using some math and vanilla ggplot2 to draw your circular plot. The plot still requires some further tweaks to set the alignment and/or positions for the labels.
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data |>
  rename_with(tolower) |>
  add_count(cluster) |>
  arrange(cluster, symptom) |>
  mutate(
    across(c(cluster, symptom), list(alpha = ~ as.numeric(forcats::fct_inorder(.x)))),
    # + c(0, 1) extend the range to avoid that first and last point overlap
    symptom_alpha = scales::rescale(symptom_alpha, to = range(cluster_alpha) + c(0, 1)),
    across(
      c(cluster_alpha, symptom_alpha),
      # Rotate by pi / 4
      ~ scales::rescale(.x,
        to = c(0, 2 * pi) + pi / 4,
        from = range(.x) + c(0, 1)
      )
    ),
    cluster_x = cos(cluster_alpha) - sin(cluster_alpha),
    cluster_y = cos(cluster_alpha) + sin(cluster_alpha),
    symptom_x = cos(symptom_alpha) - sin(symptom_alpha),
    symptom_y = cos(symptom_alpha) + sin(symptom_alpha),
    across(c(symptom_x, symptom_y), ~ .x * 2),
    cluster_hjust = +(cluster_alpha > 5 / 4 * pi),
    symptom_hjust = +(symptom_alpha < 5 / 4 * pi),
  )

dat |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_segment(aes(
    x = symptom_x, xend = cluster_x,
    y = symptom_y, yend = cluster_y,
    color = cluster
  )) +
  geom_point(
    data = ~ distinct(.x, cluster, .keep_all = TRUE),
    aes(
      x = cluster_x, y = cluster_y,
      size = n, fill = cluster
    ),
    shape = 21
  ) +
  geom_point(
    aes(x = symptom_x, y = symptom_y),
    shape = 21, fill = "grey", size = 3
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = ~ distinct(.x, symptom, .keep_all = TRUE),
    aes(
      x = 1.05 * symptom_x, y = 1.05 * symptom_y,
      label = label_wrap_gen(width = 15)(symptom),
      hjust = symptom_hjust
    ),
    size = 6 / .pt
  ) +
  geom_text(
    data = ~ distinct(.x, cluster, .keep_all = TRUE),
    aes(
      x = .8 * cluster_x, y = .8 * cluster_y,
      label = label_wrap_gen(width = 10)(cluster),
      hjust = cluster_hjust
    ),
    size = 6 / .pt
  ) +
  scale_size_area(max_size = 12) +
  theme_void() +
  guides(fill = "none", size = "none", color = "none") +
  coord_equal(clip = "off")


DATA
data <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  Cluster = c(
    "Arthritis/Myalgias",
    "Autonomic", "Autonomic", "Cardiac", "Cardiac", "Cognitive",
    "Cognitive", "Dermatologic", "Dermatologic", "Fatigue",
    "Fever/Chills", "Fever/Chills", "Gastrointestinal",
    "Gastrointestinal", "Mood", "Mood", "Mood",
    "Multisystem Inflammatory Syndrome", "Neurologic", "Neurologic", "Neurologic",
    "Neurologic", "Neurologic", "Respiratory", "Respiratory",
    "Respiratory", "Respiratory", "Sleep"
  ),
  Symptom = c(
    "New Muscle Aches (myalgia), Joint Aches, Body Aches, or Pain",
    "Fast-beating or Pounding Heart (heart palpitations)", "Dizziness",
    "Fast-beating or Pounding Heart (heart palpitations)", "Chest Pain",
    "Brain Fog (worsened memory or concentration)",
    "Confusion", "Hair Loss", "Rash", "Fatigue or Tiredness",
    "Fever or Feeling Feverish", "Chills", "Diarrhea", "Nausea",
    "Feeling Anxious or Worried", "Feeling Depressed",
    "Other Mood Changes", "Multisystem Inflammatory Syndrome, MIS",
    "Headache", "Change in Smell", "Change in Taste",
    "Loss or Change in Vision", "Tinnitus (ringing in ears)", "Cough",
    "Sore Throat", "Runny Nose and/or Nasal Congestion",
    "Shortness of Breath (Dyspnea) or Difficulty Breathing",
    "Sleep Problems"
  )
)

